# Is it possible to meta query trough a start and end date?

Tags: wordpress

So I have a post type "shipments" with a start_date and end_date as meta. How can I query shipments by meta when I want to retrieve the shipments where the date goes trough a given start_date and end_date.

Example:
(Format is YYYY-MM-DD)
Shipment Y starts on 2020-11-01 and ends on 2020-11-30.
With the query I give 2020-11-10 as start date and 2020-11-20 as end date. Since these dates are between shipment Y it's start and end date it should be retrieved.

```
    function sort_shipments_dates($query)
{
    // Get the post type
    $post_type = isset($_GET['post_type']) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

    if (is_admin() && $post_type == 'shipment') {
        // Add shipment_start_date filter if user entered a value.
        if (!empty($_GET['shipment_start_date'])) {
            $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'shipment_start_date',
                'value'   => $_GET['shipment_start_date'],
                'compare' => '>='
            );
        }

        // Add shipment_end_date filter if user entered a value.
        if (!empty($_GET['shipment_end_date'])) {
            $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'shipment_end_date',
                'value'   => $_GET['shipment_end_date'],
                'compare' => '<='
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at WP_Query arguments? There is a `meta_query` argument and one of the compares is `between`.

Comment: Can you post your code? Without it, this question will likely get closed.

Comment: Post your code or this question will get closed.

Comment: The point of you posting it is for us to help you. We can see what you are doing that doesn't work - and offer assistance. Without your code, the question becomes "code this for me" which will get the question closed.